# как через adb shell прописать номер симки

Tags: android, adb, android-adb

Например, вот так я меняю imei (оба, двухсимочный телефон)

```
  echo 'AT+EGMR=1,7,"тут номер imei1"' > /dev/radio/pttycmd1
  echo 'AT+EGMR=1,10,"тут номер imei2"' > /dev/radio/pttycmd1
```

предполагаю, что так же можно и номер симкарты указывать (например если его нет, не видно в настройках телефона)

так вот, как мне указать номера для обоих слотов? чтоб в телелефоне в настройках они отображались

как то... так типа...

```
   echo 'тут вот.. команда сама.. но какая' > /dev/smd11

  echo 'AT+CPBW=1,"+79990000000"' > /dev/smd11 
  так вот.. не работает, не пойму...
```

/dev/smd11 - это устройство у которого владелец radio, в моём случае, так что... туда команды надо посылать однозначно

Comment: Что за девайс? Или эмулятор?

Comment: blackview BV4900pro

Comment: уже решил вопрос))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для сим 1:

```
echo -e 'AT+CPBS="ON"' > /dev/radio/atci1 && echo 'AT+CPBW=1,"+79990000000"' > /dev/radio/atci1
```

для сим 2:

```
echo -e 'AT+CPBS="ON"' > /dev/radio/atci2 && echo 'AT+CPBW=1,"+79990000000"' > /dev/radio/atci2
```

/dev/radio/atci1 и /dev/radio/atci2 пути к модему 1 и 2 симки
аппарат blackview 4900pro

[вот полезная инфа по командам АТ](https://wiki.iarduino.ru/page/a6_gprs_at/#AT_CPBW)